# Is there a Terran wall-in guide?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

Does some kind of Terran wall-in guide exist that focuses on the different ramp types. I struggle with some of the strange 2v2 ramps, especially if they face northeast and I want addons on my Barracks very fast.

Sometimes my wall is not complete or the buildings are weirdly paced so my units cannot defend very well as the buildings take up too much space. Other times my ally helps me wall-in but he places his buildings so I cannot add addons without breaking the wall.

I always think that I am at a disadvantage if my base faces northeast.

Comment: Did you turn on the building grid in options? With the grid it's not really necessary to have a guide imo.

Comment: Depending on the different sides it varies whether or not you will be able to immediately place an add-on. Most of the time you need to fly it back then place it down. On the 2v2 ramps normally you can place a supply depot on each side of the ramp then wall in with two barracks in the middle. But definitely turn grid on.

Comment: The only advice I have is to play the game a great deal more.  This is one of the most basic concepts in the game.

Comment: Dude I am diamond :) and I have the grid enabled.

Comment: @ayckoster ever find anything that was particularly helpful with this? I just started playing the game with my brother, and his zerglings are sneaking right by my supply depot wall! lol . I think the map we play on just has really wide ramps that are hard to block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the building grid is enabled in Options, that will help you place buildings on the fly without having to memorise anything.

As for your ally blocking addons, your best bet is to lift the building and build the addon elsewhere when you're ready, while replacing it in the wall with supply depots.  Alternatively, you could use the Voice over IP client to plan out your wall in with your ally.

Comment: You can use just about any voice chat software...

Comment: True, but Blizzard kindly built one in, and if ayckoster is doing random partner 2v2's, coordinating VOIP clients in the beginning stages of the game seems like an extra challenge. If he isn't doing random partner, he should just yell at his partner to not block his add-ons.

Comment: Except their voice system often fails... some get it to work while many do not.

Comment: Haven't used it in a while, but haven't had any trouble myself. He should give it a try to see if it works for coordinating with random allies if that is indeed his situation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, 2 depots and 1 barracks will work. If you want add-ons? lift off your barracks and incorporate said add-on in the wall. Just don't research with it early on in case the enemy is trying to bust the wall w/banelings, etc.

Note that I don't main terran and the last time i did this was a few months ago. It worked well when i did, though.